# Trouble with Tuples and Lists in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I need to find a way to take a data set and change a few values.

Data is in this format: *(name, age, wealth)*

```
list = [(Donald, 25, 500), (Chris, 28, 450), (Susan, 23, 650)]
```

I need to use a `for` loop and the indices of both the tuple and the list to change the wealth of each person to exactly 1000.

Comment: Tuples are immutable, once constructed, you can not change the *elements*. What have you tried yourself?

Comment: And where did you get stuck when you tried to do this? Please do share your attempts so we can help correct *those*.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  And it is difficult for me to say where I got stuck because I've had no programming classes.  I'm taking a course, but cannot attend since the classes all overlap with other classes on my schedule and the professor has a 'no questions' policy.  This is literally the first time I've seen Python and I'm just scouring the internet trying to solve these problems.

Comment: Okay, so I am still getting stuck.  This is what I have tried:

list = [(Donald, 25, 500), (Chris, 28, 450), (Susan, 23, 650)]
for i, (name, age, wealth) in enumerate(list):
       list[i] = [(x,y,1000) for (x,y,z) in list]
print (list)

This is what I get when I run it:  [[('Donald', 25, 1000), ('Chris', 28, 1000), ('Susan', 23, 1000)], [(('Donald', 25, 1000), ('Chris', 28, 1000), 1000), ('Chris', 28, 1000), ('Susan', 23, 1000)], [(('Donald', 25, 1000), ('Chris', 28, 1000), 1000), ((('Donald', 25, 1000), ('Chris', 28, 1000), 1000), ('Chris', 28, 1000), 1000), ('Susan', 23, 1000)]]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
list = [(Donald, 25, 500), (Chris, 28, 450), (Susan, 23, 650)]

for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = (list[i][0],list[i][1],1000)
```

Since `tuple` is immutable you need to create a brand new `tuple`.

You could also create a new `list` this way:

```
list = [(Donald, 25, 500), (Chris, 28, 450), (Susan, 23, 650)]
list2 = []
for t in list:
    list2.append(t[0],t[1],1000)
```

This is a `for-each` like way to iterate through your list.

Another 2 compact and easy ways, as @Martijn Pieters♦ suggests is to use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) like this:

```
list = [(Donald, 25, 500), (Chris, 28, 450), (Susan, 23, 650)]
list = [(x,y,1000) for (x,y,z) in list]
```

or `enumerate()` like this:

```
list = [(Donald, 25, 500), (Chris, 28, 450), (Susan, 23, 650)]
for i, (name, age, wealth) in enumerate(list):
    list[i] = (name,age,1000)
```

Comment: You really should learn about `enumerate()`, or list comprehensions.

Comment: I know `enumerate()` but haven't used it a lot in my experience, how can it be useful here? (not criticizing, just asking to learn)

Comment: If you used `for i, (name, age, wealth) in enumerate(lst):`, you don't need to use `range()` or indexing.

Comment: You're right sir! I'll add it to the answer too, thanks!

Comment: Last but not least, try not to use the name `list`; you are masking the built-in. That can lead to issues elsewhere, like `TypeError: 'list' object is not callable` when you try to use `list()` to convert something to a list.

Comment: You're right. I was just mantaining the OP variable's name though. I always avoid to choose these names!

Comment: It's never too late to teach others though; answers are here for the long term, not just the current asker.